# Como colocar um Id AUTOINCREMENT?

Tags: sql, python, sqlite3, atom

Estou fazendo uma tabela de login, onde que se faz o registro de login, add os dados do seu serviço e add um empresa a qual você trabalha. Porém estou com dificuldade na hora de add o Id do usuário. Eu quero que assim q a pessoa faça seu registro, o programa já puxe o id automático deste novo usuário e add automaticamente na hora que ele add a empresa que trabalha. Atualmente eu tenho que pedir para o usuário add seu Id de forma  manual. (Python com sqlite3)

```
def inserir_trabalho_cliente(conexao):
    cursor =  conexao.cursor()
    cargo       = input("Qual é o seu cargo? ")
    hrs         = int(input("Quantas horas você trabalha por semana? "))
    salario     = float(input("Qual é o seu salário? "))
    admissao    = input("Qual é a sua data de admissão? ")
    id_usuario  = int(input("Qual é o seu Id de usuário? "))

    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
    print("AGORA VAMOS ADICIONAR A EMPRESA QUE VOCÊ TRABALHA")
    x = int(input("Adcionar um empresa = 1 \nEscolher uma empresa já adcionada = 2\nR: "))
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')

    if(x == 1):
        empresa.inserir_empresa(conexao)
        os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')

        empresa.listar_empresa(conexao)
        id_empresa = int(input("Qual é o codigo da empresa que trabalha? "))

        sql = '''INSERT INTO trabalho (usu_cargo, usu_horas_trabalho_semanal, usu_salario, data_admissao,
    id_empresa, id_usuario) VALUES  ('{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', {}, {})'''.format(cargo, hrs,
    salario, admissao, id_empresa, id_usuario)

        cursor.execute(sql)
        conexao.commit()

    elif(x == 2 ):
        empresa.listar_empresa(conexao)
        id_empresa  = int(input("Qual é o Id da empresa que trabalha? "))

        sql = '''INSERT INTO trabalho (usu_cargo, usu_horas_trabalho_semanal, usu_salario, data_admissao,
    id_empresa, id_usuario) VALUES  ('{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', {}, {})'''.format(cargo, hrs,
    salario, admissao, id_empresa, id_usuario)

        cursor.execute(sql)
        conexao.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Quando você cria uma tabela no `sqlite`, a não ser que seja usada a opção `WITHOUT ROWID`, sempre é criada uma coluna chamada `rowid` que é `autoincrement`, então o valor dessa coluna já serve como esse id que precisa, basta incluir no seu select o `rowid`.

Veja o exemplo funcionando aqui: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/faaaf/2

Note que ao criar a tabela não foi especificado uma coluna `autoincrement`, mas ela foi criada e tem valores.